# How to get the scaled width/height in imageview after postscale()

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, zooming, pinch

I have a code which allow user to pinch-zoom some images on the screen.
I use AbsoluteLayout and imageviews to display the images.
In order to achieve this, I made those imageviews have full width/height to its parent.
Then when user touch a point, I will detect which image is under that point area, and use bringChildToFront() so it has focus for onTouch() event.
When user make a pinch-zoom, I use matrix and its postScale() method, using this code
[android imageView: setting drag and pinch zoom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227451/android-imageview-setting-drag-and-pinch-zoom-parameters)

Now, what makes me confuse is, how to get the current width/height of the image after postScale()?
I've tried:

1. `getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()`
   <-- didnt work. It's always return
   the original width/height
2. `getDrawable().getBounds().width()`
   <-- same as above
3. `getDrawingCache().getWidth()` <--
   this just returns the width/height
   of the imageview

So, what is the appropriate way to achieve this?
Thanks.

-ri

Answer (score 0):

Ri-

Here is my solution for the same problem that I had using the Pinch zoom/Drag pan. You can adapt it to your own needs. I put this inside the zoom portion of the MotionEvent.Action_Move

```
 else if (mode ==ZOOM){
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            if(newDist > 10f){
                int height;
                int width;
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist/oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale,scale,mid.x,mid.y);
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                height = (int)(ivViewPoint.y * scale);
                width = (int)(ivViewPoint.x * scale);
                ivViewPoint = new Point(width,height);


            }
```

Hope that helps out.