# Implement Pinch to zoom on ImageView inside a gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I am implementing pinch-zoom on ImageView in my App.I am having an Activity which is holding Gallery view and I am showing my ImageView inside gallery.Independently pich-zoom is working and I am able to handle gallery fling also when image is in normal size But my problem is:
How to fling when Image is in some zoom level.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582833/how-to-enable-the-two-finger-zoom-in-out-feature-for-an-image-in-android/7582999#7582999

Comment: Did any answer help you to solve your problem? if yes then mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this links that adds panning, zoom, and boundary detection to ImageView.

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910)

Answer (score 0):

Generally Gallery include Two functionality

- Zooming current Image showing to User
- And swiping to next/previous Image

Issue is when we zoom Image inside a Gallery, it should disable the swipe view. It should only swipe when Zoom Image Drag reach to end.

This [post Tell about how to zoom an Image Perfectly](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/update-pinch-to-zoom-example-and.html). Now you have to take one ViewPager and integrate both