# ViewPager & ImageView zooming issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I am trying to implement a Gallery of images using ViewPager. Also, to implement zoom feature in that, I am using [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) from github. I have also tried using [ZoomableImageView](https://github.com/a85/WebComicViewer/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/ui/ZoomableImageView.java).

But, the problem is, if I zoom the image & if I scroll the image , then instead of image, `ViewPager` is getting scrolled & next view of `ViewPager` is getting loaded.

If I zoom the image then if I scroll that, then image has to move instead of `ViewPager`

ViewPager's next view has to load only if reach the end of the zoomed image. How to do that?

I am not able to find that.If I touch & drag the image diagonally, only then image is getting moved. or else ViewPager's drag is getting invoked.

ps: this is not duplicate. Zooming is done. But the problem is after image zooming.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes I too had the same problem not with TouchImageView.

Too solved the problem what i did is disabled the ViewPager when my view is getting the focus.

```
public class EnableDisableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled = true;

    public EnableDisableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        if(enabled)
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

so in TouchImageView implement your listener to trigger an event whether its zooming or dragging.

set listener to your view object in your Activity. So when those event occur just disable the view Pager.

**Note**: you will also need a mouse up event to enable the viewpager.

**EDITED**

This will work only for Zoom, so for ViewPager to swipe pages you should zoom back to original.

Add these code to your TouchImageView

```
    public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

        ...
    private TouchEventListener touchEventListener;

        private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
            ...

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    ...
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            ...
                            if(touchEventListener != null)
                            {
                                if(saveScale == 1.0)
                                    touchEventListener.onZoomToOriginal();
                                else
                                    touchEventListener.onZoom();
                            }
                            break;

                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                }

            });
        }

        ...

public TouchEventListener getTouchEventListener() {
        return touchEventListener;
    }

    public void setTouchEventListener(TouchEventListener touchEventListener) {
        this.touchEventListener = touchEventListener;
    }


        public interface TouchEventListener 
        {
            void onZoom();
            void onZoomToOriginal();
        }
    }
```

**BETTER SOLUTION**

We could achieve this without extending ViewPager to a new Class by using the method given below.

```
requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

And with this we could swipe without zooming out to original position as we see in Gallery and many other apps.

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

        ...
private void stopInterceptEvent()
{
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
}

private void startInterceptEvent()
{
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    stopInterceptEvent();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                        if (scaleWidth < width) {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        } else {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }

                        if(deltaX == 0)
                            startInterceptEvent();
                        else
                            stopInterceptEvent();

                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    startInterceptEvent();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Ya please revise the TouchImageView. I am really working very hard on it. I am not able to find solution. It would be really helpful if you can help me in that!! Please update your answer with the revised TouchImageView.

Comment: What are the variables width, height, right, bottom ?  didn't mentioned it.

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal thnak u very much, but the image is still being cut at the edges sometimes by the other image; Plus my image was filling its parent now it's smaller why? thanks.

Comment: Thank you Vivek this works with me, lot of time saved, thank you again!

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal What are width, height, right and bottom?

Comment: check my GitHub fork in above comments you will get complete source

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my days :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding this code:

```
if(deltaX == 0 &&  saveScale == 1.0 )
    startInterceptEvent();
else
    stopInterceptEvent();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) library, which works even with standard ViewPager from Android Support Package without any customisations.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(deltaX == 0 || saveScale == 1.0 )
    startInterceptEvent();
else
    stopInterceptEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone have a horizontal viewpager, is important change @kirit-vaghela code:

```
if(deltaX == 0 || saveScale == 1.0 )
    startInterceptEvent();
else
    stopInterceptEvent();
```

To

```
if(saveScale == 1.0 )
    startInterceptEvent();
else
    stopInterceptEvent();
```

So the adapter's gonna change the picture only when is 1.0