# Not displaying image in viewpager

Tags: android

I want to load four image in view pager, i am actually loading images from drawable folder but i am not able to load these,

below is the code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@id/pager1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ncard1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/tncard2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/tncard3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/tncard4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Look i am displaying images from drawable but i am getting blank view pager

please help me

Comment: Please Show your code which you have implemented

Comment: that is the code that i have implemented, i have done nothing in java

Comment: you have to set images in View pager dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use answer of the following question I have tested this and is working fine..

[View Pager + ImageView +Pinch Zoom + Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943831/view-pager-imageview-pinch-zoom-rotation/20944068#20944068)