# How to implement zoom, pan and drag on Viewpager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, touchimageview

How to implement zoom, pan and drag on Viewpager in android?

I have kept my images inside the viewpager ,here i could not able to pan and zoom .please kindly let me know how to do

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement zoom, pan and drag on Viewpager in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306037/how-to-implement-zoom-pan-and-drag-on-viewpager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [this](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery).
Here is implemented the zoom and pan functionalities over Viewpager.