# Implementing Tap Zooming

Tags: android

I have created Two Apps Pinch Zooming and Double Tap Zooming but i m not getting how to implement Single Tap Zooming.

Is anybody knows, how to implement Tap Zooming?

Comment: can you share where you learnt pinch zoom and double tab zoom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227451/android-imageview-setting-drag-and-pinch-zoom-parameters

Comment: Or else refer Hello Android 3rd Edition by Ed  Burnette...

Comment: For Double Tap refer this link

Comment: http://androidprogrammingmadeeasy.blogspot.in/2011/08/zoom-image-on-double-tap-in-android.html

Comment: refer http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/