# How to resize an ImageView while dragging with two fingers?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am new to Android. I have rectangular and circular ImageViews. I need to resize these ImageViews with two fingers (e.g. while dragging with two fingers, that ImageView should be resizable).

Comment: There are a few good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images I recommend google before posting new questions. Its likely they have already been asked.

Comment: thanks for giving answer i saw that link before but that is customised imageview here i don't want create a customised imageview. here i added imageview dynamically in my code. - Doomsknight

Comment: If you want the extra zoom functionality it needs to be customised. And you can add it dynamically in the same way.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227451/android-imageview-setting-drag-and-pinch-zoom-parameters) shows how to drag and zoom on a regular ImageView.  It doesn't resize the view, it just alters the underlying canvas.  I use it for pinch to zoom in several apps and it works great.

Comment: Hi thanks for giving your suggestions but I am not getting correctly. I want pinch and zoom in image view it is in map and below of this image some pins are there those pins also clickble events handling. When I through what you are providing links its not working for me. Can any one give a suggestions plz.