# how to move and zoom image view with in screen boundaries in android

Tags: android, android-listview

hi i need to zoom and move my image  using below code its working well.but here i have some issues.1 when i gave src as background to image view  that time its working,if i gave background using setbackgroundresource() means my imageview zoom and  move actions not working. 2.for imageview if gave background fillparent that time only its working fine for both zoom and move.if gave  set width 100,and hight 100 that time both zoom and move not working..i need to display my imageview with 100/100 dimensions and i need to zoom and move that image with in a screen boundaries..what i have to do any one suggest please...please

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

private static final String TAG = "Touch";

     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

   static final int NONE = 0;
   static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
       int mode = NONE;

PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
     float oldDist = 1f;
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp3;
    ImageView view;
    RelativeLayout relativemiddlemain;


     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 relativemiddlemain=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoomlayout);
    view = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    view.setId(0);
                    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                    view.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
                    rlp3 = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
      //                     rlp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
                    rlp3.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
          //                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                      view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             relativemiddlemain.addView(view,rlp3);

    }

 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

   view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

   float scale;
    // Dump touch event to log

   dumpEvent(event);

  // Handle touch events here...

   switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only

      savedMatrix.set(matrix);

      start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );

      mode = DRAG;

      break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted

      mode = NONE;

      Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );

      break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down

      oldDist = spacing(event);

      Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);

      if (oldDist > 5f) {

         savedMatrix.set(matrix);

         midPoint(mid, event);

         mode = ZOOM;

         Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );

      }

      break;



   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger

         matrix.set(savedMatrix);

         if (view.getLeft() >= -392){

            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);

         }

      }

      else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming

         float newDist = spacing(event);

         Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);

         if (newDist > 5f) {

            matrix.set(savedMatrix);

            scale = newDist / oldDist; /*thinking i need to play around with this value to limit it*/

            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

         }

      }

      break;

   }



   // Perform the transformation

   view.setImageMatrix(matrix);



   return true; // indicate event was handled

}



private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {

   float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);

   float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

   return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

}



private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {

   float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);

   float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);

   point.set(x / 2, y / 2);

}



/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */

private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {

   String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,

      "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   int action = event.getAction();

   int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

   sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);

   if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN

         || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {

      sb.append("(pid " ).append(

      action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);

      sb.append(")" );

   }

   sb.append("[" );

   for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {

      sb.append("#" ).append(i);

      sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));

      sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));

      sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));

      if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())

         sb.append(";" );

   }

   sb.append("]" );

   Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());

}

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android imageView: setting drag and pinch zoom parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227451/android-imageview-setting-drag-and-pinch-zoom-parameters)

Comment: Did you find the proper solution for it? It would be great if you can share it here for others to understand..